# Is there another way to loop a array in spans with the class "tags"

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays, loops

I'm setting up a Local Server and want to create a loop for a dictionary(array) so that results are presented in spans with the class "tags". So that there later can used like a button. But the code doesn't loop, my question is if there another way to loop this code

I already writhe code several times but the code doesnt work, even the console of the Browser shows no error

```html
    <script>
    var ports_dic = [16, 17, 18, 19, 20];
    
    function loop_ports(){   
      var n_list = document.value = ports_dic["1/1/12"] 
      for (var i = 0; i < n_list.length; i++){
      var span = document.createElement("SPAN");
      span_element = console.log(ports_dict[i]);
      span.appendChild(span_element);
      document.getElementById("onu_tags").appendChild(span);
     };
    }
    </script>
    <body>
      <div id="onu_tags" class="tags">
           
      </div>
    </body>
```

I expect the output in "tags"
16
17
18
19
20
but there isn't a output

Comment: You've created a function but I don't see you calling it.

Comment: What the use of div tag inside the function

Comment: This is a simplified version i already call the funtion by a Onclick but there are more details in the function but there already work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
 var ports_dic = [16, 17, 18, 19, 20];
    
    function loop_ports(){   
    
     for (var i = 0; i < ports_dic.length; i++){
     var node = document.createElement("LI");                 // Create a <li> node
var textnode = document.createTextNode(ports_dic[i]);         // Create a text node
node.appendChild(textnode);                              // Append the text to <li>
document.getElementById("onu_tags").appendChild(node);     // Append <li> to <ul> with id="myList"

     };
    }
```

```html
    <body onload="loop_ports()">
      <ul id="onu_tags" class="tags">
           
      </ul>
    </body>
```

You forgot to make your dictionary items into text nodes (also you didn't need the console.log bit).

Answer (score 0):

ports_dic is not a dictionary, and you are not creating a span_element, instead, you are assigning "console.log()" to the variable span_element. Please double check before posting

```
<script>
var ports_dic = {"1/1/12":[16, 17, 18, 19, 20]};

function loop_ports(){   
  var n_list = document.value = ports_dic["1/1/12"] 
  for (var i = 0; i < n_list.length; i++){
        var span = document.createElement("SPAN");
        span_element = console.log(n_list[i]);
        span.appendChild(span_element);
        document.getElementById("onu_tags").appendChild(span);
    };
}
</script>
<body onload="loop_ports()">
  <div id="onu_tags" class="tags">

  </div>
</body>
```

```js
    var ports_dic = {"1/1/12":[16, 17, 18, 19, 20]};
    
    function loop_ports(){   
      var n_list = document.value = ports_dic["1/1/12"] 
      for (var i = 0; i < n_list.length; i++){
      var span = document.createElement("SPAN");
      var span_element = document.createTextNode(n_list[i]);
      span.appendChild(span_element);
      document.getElementById("onu_tags").appendChild(span);
     };
    }
```

```html
    <body onload="loop_ports()">
      <div id="onu_tags" class="tags">
           
      </div>
    </body>
```